# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'month1' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just started practicing some C++ for an exam and I got this error, any idea how to fix it? 
"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'month1' was corrupted"

```
 here's my code: 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "pch.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h> 

 int main()
 {
     char month[10] = "January";
     printf("%s\n", month);

     month[0] = 'J';
     month[1] = 'u';
     month[2] = 'l';
     month[3] = 'y';
     month[4] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n", month);


    char month1[10];
    printf("%s\n", month1);
    month1[0] = 'J';
    month1[1] = 'u';
    month1[2] = 'l';
    month1[3] = 'y';
    month1[4] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n" , month1);


    char month2[10];
    strcpy(month2, "April");
    printf("%s\n", month2);
    strcpy(month2, "Too many characters");
    printf("%s\n", month2);
     }
```

Comment: The error is spot on: Your last `strcpy` filled up `month2[0]` through `month2[9]` and then continued, overwriting bits of `month1` and `month` as well. If you inspect this program with a debugger, and pause right after the strcpy, you will see how the contents of `month1` and `month` change.

Comment: As you tagged this question with 'visual-studio', you should have received warnings about replacing `strcpy` with `strcpy_s`, at which point your program should no longer compile. Alternatively you can go with `strncpy`, or just stop using character arrays in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function strcpy doesn't check to see if the character array you want to copy into is large enough to hold the string you're wanting to copy.  Your code will cause a buffer overrun.  I don't recommend doing this unless you're trying to hack something.

```
char month2[10];
strcpy(month2, "April");
printf("%s\n", month2);
strcpy(month2, "Too many characters"); // Buffer overrun.  Your string even hints at this.
printf("%s\n", month2);
```

You are also printing an uninitialized string which may cause other issues.  Using printf with the %s format specifier will cause the array you're passing to be treated as a null-terminated string.  It will print characters until it reaches a 0 ('\0') so the output string could end up being very large.

```
char month1[10];
printf("%s\n", month1); // <- Printing uninitialized string
```